# Shortcut key to close Immediate window in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, key, shortcut

What is the shortcut key to close Immediate window in Visual Studio 2010.
I open it using <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

I want to close it using shortcut key with dock mode.

Comment: Press Shift-Esc, it will hide the tool window

Comment: Dock it so you don't spend your life closing it over and over again.

Comment: Off-topic, but I had lost my Immediate window, and your keyboard shortcut brought it back.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

This is the correct answer. It's already in several comments.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the immediate window (close any document window or e.g. a tab).

Comment: Ctrl+F4 only closes tabs, if it is a floating dock window, you need to use Shift-Esc.

Comment: ^ This comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing Escape one or more times will take you back to the active code-window.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to do it via window menu: Alt + -, H